# WebView2 with caret-browsing mode enabled

Tags: webview2

Is it possible to programmatically enable caret-browsing mode in the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control?

I have tried setting the chromium command-line argument, to no avail (other arguments, such as --diagnostics, work fine).

```
auto wv2opts = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();

// https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
wv2opts->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--enable-caret-browsing"); 

hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr,nullptr,wv2opts.Get(),
         Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
         this,&AppWindow::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, by reading [the caret navigation design document](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdgeExplainers/blob/main/Accessibility/CaretBrowsing/designDoc.md), [the available blink options](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/settings.json5?q=settings.json5&ss=chromium) and [the Chromium command-line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

The short version is that you set this in the blink settings of Chromium:

```
auto wv2opts = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
wv2opts->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--blink-settings=caretBrowsingEnabled"); 
hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr,nullptr,
         wv2opts.Get(),
         Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
         this,&AppWindow::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());
```

Note that blink settings are global to the WebView2 [process group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/process-model?tabs=csharp), and apply to all WebView2 controls created in the WebView2 process group. To get separate WebView2 process groups, we can supply unique data folder locations, like this:

```
   hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr,this->GetUniqueDataPath(),
             wv2opts.Get(),
             Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
             this,&AppWindow::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());
```

...and voilá!, we get to pick and choose which ones have caret-mode enabled or not.